# Does java have compile time binding?

Tags: java, java-me

it is said that overloading have compile time binding in java but actually object created at  run time so I am confused how compile time binding take place.

Answer (score 2):

It means that the compiler works out which overload to use based solely on the compile-time type of the expressions involved. Sample code:

```
class Parent
{
    void foo(Object x)
    {
        System.out.println("Parent.foo(Object)");
    }
}

class Child extends Parent
{
    void foo(String x)
    {
        System.out.println("Child.foo(String)");
    }
}


public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Child c = new Child();
        c.foo("hello"); // Calls Child.foo(String)
        Parent p = c;
        p.foo("hello"); // Calls Parent.foo(Object)
    }
}
```

Note how the declared type of the variable (`Parent` or `Child` for `p` and `c` respectively) determines which overloads are considered.

Note that this is *not* the same as overriding, which is based on the *execution-time* type of the target object.

Comment: if we swap the method of Parent and Child than why its giving compile time error "The method foo(Object) is ambiguous for the type Child". in c.foo("hello") line.

Comment: @Vivart: Because at that point the compiler is balancing two ways in which an overload can be "better" - a method declared in a subclass is preferred to a method declared in a superclass, but a method with a more specific parameter (e.g. String) is preferred to one with a more general parameter (e.g. Object).